# How to use RMixpanel library to export data in csv

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, mixpanel

Does anyone aware of using `RMixpanel` library, if yes. How can we export mixpanel data using this library and export it into csv or xlsx format.

It would be great if any author or maintainer of this library can guide us through all functions of this useful library using small-small examples.

Answer (score 4):

The function `profilesJson2RMatrix` provides a method for converting JSON to R matrix. You can then write the the object using `write.csv` function.

Checkout the github page for a working example of using this page:
https://github.com/ploner/RMixpanel

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of the package `RMixpanel`. In Mixpanel there are two big data collections:

- "People" (i.e. User Profiles)
- "Events"

The code to export **People Profiles** is:

```
require(RMixpanel)

profiles = mixpanelGetProfiles(account)
write.csv2(profiles, file="profiles.csv")
```

You can also narrow down the export by a condition (parameter `where`) or by selecting only a list of *People Properties* (parameter `select`). The `README` of the package shows how a condition is applied.

The code to export **Events** is:

```
events = mixpanelGetEvents(account, from="2018-09-15")
write.csv2(events, file="events.csv")
```

You can also export a subset of the *Events*, a certain time frame, or only a subset of *Event Properties* and/or *Super Properties*.